# Cannot use AWS SES to send email by Django application sit in AWS EC2

Tags: django, amazon-ec2, amazon-ses

I have a Django application which sit in AWS EC2, i want to connect to AWS SES to send Email, so i followed this tutorial:
https://kholinlabs.com/the-easiest-way-to-send-emails-with-django

First , i created an EC2 instance in ap-southeast-1a avalibility zone, which the inbound and outbound rules are as following:

inbound rule:

```
HTTP    TCP 80  0.0.0.0/0
All traffic All All 0.0.0.0/0
All traffic All All ::/0
SSH TCP 22  0.0.0.0/0
SMTPS   TCP 465 0.0.0.0/0
SMTPS   TCP 465 ::/0
HTTPS   TCP 443 0.0.0.0/0
```

outbound rule:

```
All traffic All All 0.0.0.0/0
All traffic All All ::/0
```

then i created Django application inside the server:

```
django-admin startproject mysite
python3 manage.py makemigrations
python3 manage.py migrate
```

add the following lines in setting file:

```
EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django_ses.SESBackend'
AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID = 'secret'
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY = 'secret'
AWS_SES_REGION_NAME = 'ap-southeast-2'
AWS_SES_REGION_ENDPOINT = 'email-smtp.ap-southeast-2.amazonaws.com'
```

then i created an SES instance in ap-southeast-2 avalibility zone.

inside EC2 server, i follow the tutorial and type commands:

```
python3 manage.py shell
from django.core.mail import send_mail
send_mail(
    'Subject here',
    'Here is the message.',
    'from@example.com',
    ['to@example.com']
)
```

but it stuck for very long time (around 10 mins) and then show timeout message.

is there any step i missed?

---

other info:
for telnet:

```
 telnet email-smtp.ap-southeast-2.amazonaws.com 465
Trying 3.24.207.252...
Connected to email-smtp.ap-southeast-2.amazonaws.com.
Escape character is '^]'.
```

465 port can work

```
 telnet email-smtp.ap-southeast-2.amazonaws.com 25
Trying 13.238.20.185...
```

it stuck for port 25

```
telnet email-smtp.ap-southeast-2.amazonaws.com 587
Trying 3.24.207.252...
Connected to email-smtp.ap-southeast-2.amazonaws.com.
Escape character is '^]'.
220 email-smtp.amazonaws.com ESMTP SimpleEmailService-d-EHZHT2N2F i9ibRsZcZvQJA54s7GtJ
451 4.4.2 Timeout waiting for data from client.
Connection closed by foreign host.
```

Answer (score 0):

You appear to be trying to send mail from `from@example.com`. This will not work. Update the sender and receiver addresses to emails you have verified on SES. See below on how to verify addresses.

Also make sure you have replaced `'secret'`

```
AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID = 'secret'
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY = 'secret'
```

with the actual access key id and secret key you got from the aws console.

You can see how to verify emails addresses here:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/verify-email-addresses.html

and how to get out of the sandbox here:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/request-production-access.html

Comment: Hi, David Stein , thank you very much , but i verified my email address , and use the email address to send to my email address
```
send_mail(
    'Subject here',
    'Here is the message.',
    'dnaqazxsw@gmail.com',
    ['dnaqazxsw@gmail.com']
)
```
and i use my own AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID and AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY,
because of security issue, so i replaced them as 'secret' here, but actually i am using my own credential.
but now it still stuck when i execute the command, do you have any more idea about it?

Comment: >>> from django.core.mail import send_mail
>>> send_mail(
...     'Subject here',
...     'Here is the message.',
...     'dnadnadnareal@gmail.com',
...     ['dnadnadnareal@gmail.com']
... )
(stuck)

Comment: sorry for the content cannot be formatted while adding comment

Comment: I see, take a look at this to help with your port 25 issues https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/ec2-port-25-throttle/

Comment: can i just use port 465 to send email ?
i can telent to port 465 of SES server, and then i add EMAIL_PORT = 465 in settings.py,
but it doesn't work either, why is that?

Comment: Ok I think you need to use djangos tls settings as aws does not allow unencrypted connections on port 465. Check the docs here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/email/